# slideUp/slideDown slides both (all) submenus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a sidebar using HTML, CSS and jQuery. I'm having an issue with the slideUp/slideDown not functioning correctly. For example, when I try to click on a submenu in order to close it, both opened submenus disappear. Clicking on the submenus in order to open them also isn't working correctly. I'm wondering why is this happening. I'm not sure what did I do wrong.

I have tried to `console.log($(this).find('> .submenu'));` and indeed the object is of length 1. I'm not sure why is it sliding both (all) menus.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.has-submenu').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).find('> .menu-item > .arrow').toggleClass('rotated');
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).find('> .submenu').slideDown("slow");
    } else {
      console.log($(this).find('> .submenu'));
      $(this).find('> .submenu').slideUp("slow");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,300,600);
@font-face {
  font-family: "ionicons";
  src: url("https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.eot?v=2.0.1");
  src: url("https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.eot?v=2.0.1#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.ttf?v=2.0.1") format("truetype"), url("https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.woff?v=2.0.1") format("woff"), url("https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.svg?v=2.0.1#Ionicons") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  background-color: #348ceb;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-size: 14px;
  position: fixed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul,
li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.submenu {
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: none;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  margin: 0 -1.5rem;
  background-color: #3287e3;
}

.submenu li:first-child {
  padding: 0.1rem 0 0 1.5rem;
}

.submenu li:last-child {
  padding: 0 0 0.1rem 1.5rem;
}

.submenu li {
  padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
}

.submenu li:hover {
  background-color: #3082db;
}

.menu>li:hover {
  background-color: #3287e3;
}

.menu>li {
  position: relative;
  color: #F9FAFC;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 -1.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
}

.menu>li>a {
  display: block;
  color: #F9FAFC;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.menu>li>a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.submenu>li>a {
  display: block;
  color: #F9FAFC;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 -1.5rem;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.submenu>li>a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.submenu>li {
  font-weight: normal !important;
}

.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: left center;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.75em;
}

.arrow:after {
  content: '\f125';
  font-family: 'ionicons';
  color: white;
}

.rotated {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.menu-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-item>span:first-child {
  flex: 1;
}

.sidebar-icon {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.no-submenu a {
  margin: 0 -1.5rem;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
  <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="has-submenu">
        <div class="menu-item">
          <span>Analytic plane geometry</span>
          <span class="arrow"></span>
        </div>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li class="has-submenu">
            <div class="menu-item">
              <span>Line</span>
              <span class="arrow"></span>
            </div>
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li>1</li>
              <li>2</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="has-submenu">
            <div class="menu-item">
              <span>Circle</span>
              <span class="arrow"></span>
            </div>
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li>1</li>
              <li>2</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Here is the [demo](https://codepen.io/lbastos/pen/zYGZYwJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the `.has-submenu` elements are nested. As such when you click a child the event propagates up the DOM and fires there too, so all elements get toggled. To fix this call `stopPropagation()` on the event that's passed to the handler:

```
$('.has-submenu').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  // the rest of your code...
});
```

In addition you should cache your selectors, to save re-creating a jQuery object from `this`, and you can also remove the need for the `if` condition by using `slideToggle()` instead. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.has-submenu').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    var $el = $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $el.find('> .menu-item > .arrow').toggleClass('rotated');
    $el.find('> .submenu').slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,300,600);
@font-face {
  font-family: "ionicons";
  src: url("https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.eot?v=2.0.1");
  src: url("https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.eot?v=2.0.1#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.ttf?v=2.0.1") format("truetype"), url("https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.woff?v=2.0.1") format("woff"), url("https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.svg?v=2.0.1#Ionicons") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  background-color: #348ceb;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-size: 14px;
  position: fixed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul,
li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.submenu {
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: none;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  margin: 0 -1.5rem;
  background-color: #3287e3;
}

.submenu li:first-child {
  padding: 0.1rem 0 0 1.5rem;
}

.submenu li:last-child {
  padding: 0 0 0.1rem 1.5rem;
}

.submenu li {
  padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
}

.submenu li:hover {
  background-color: #3082db;
}

.menu>li:hover {
  background-color: #3287e3;
}

.menu>li {
  position: relative;
  color: #F9FAFC;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 -1.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
}

.menu>li>a {
  display: block;
  color: #F9FAFC;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.menu>li>a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.submenu>li>a {
  display: block;
  color: #F9FAFC;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 -1.5rem;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.submenu>li>a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.submenu>li {
  font-weight: normal !important;
}

.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: left center;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.75em;
}

.arrow:after {
  content: '\f125';
  font-family: 'ionicons';
  color: white;
}

.rotated {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.menu-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-item>span:first-child {
  flex: 1;
}

.sidebar-icon {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.no-submenu a {
  margin: 0 -1.5rem;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
  <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="has-submenu">
        <div class="menu-item">
          <span>Analytic plane geometry</span>
          <span class="arrow"></span>
        </div>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li class="has-submenu">
            <div class="menu-item">
              <span>Line</span>
              <span class="arrow"></span>
            </div>
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li>1</li>
              <li>2</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="has-submenu">
            <div class="menu-item">
              <span>Circle</span>
              <span class="arrow"></span>
            </div>
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li>1</li>
              <li>2</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: ...try what? :)

Comment: It wasn't appearing, then I refreshed the page. Working, awesome. Thanks.